# Why is my Zombie enemy not chasing the player?

Tags: c++, ai, sfml

I am using C++ and SFML to make a top-down Zombie shooter. For now I have a player I can move around who can shoot but I am trying to have a basic AI for a Zombie who chases the player based on player position.

For some reason the zombie is moving in a straight direction rather than chasing player. I believe that the problem has to do with incorrect player position being used to calculate the direction of the zombie. But I can't seem to figure out how to fix the problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my code so far:

**Player.cpp**

```
//GetPosition() is getting player position
//I even tried getting output of player's x and y position in this class and 
//its correctly showing player's position
sf::Vector2f Player::GetPosition()
{
  xPos = playerSprite.getPosition().x;
  yPos = playerSprite.getPosition().y;

  sf::Vector2f position = sf::Vector2f(xPos, yPos);

  //Correctly outputs position
  std::cout << "X: " << position.x << " Y: " << position.y << std::endl;

  return position;
}


void Player::movePlayer(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
playerPosition = GetPosition();
//std::cout << "X: " << GetPosition().x << " Y: " << GetPosition().y << 
std::endl;
mousePosWindow = sf::Vector2f(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window));
if (mousePosWindow.x < 0.f || mousePosWindow.x > window.getSize().x || 
mousePosWindow.y < 0.f || mousePosWindow.y > window.getSize().y)
{
    "";
}

aimDirection = mousePosWindow - playerPosition;
aimDirNorm = aimDirection / sqrt(pow(aimDirection.x, 2) + 
pow(aimDirection.y, 2));

//Player
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left) || 
sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
{
    playerSprite.move(-5.f, 0.f);
}
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right) || 
sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
{
    playerSprite.move(5.f, 0.f);
}
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up) || 
sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
{
    playerSprite.move(0.f, -5.f);
}
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down) || 
sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
{
    playerSprite.move(0.f, 5.f);
}

//Rotate player relative to mouse position
const float PI = 3.14159265;

float dx = playerPosition.x - mousePosWindow.x;
float dy = playerPosition.y - mousePosWindow.y;

rotation = (atan2(dy, dx)) * 180 / PI;

playerSprite.setRotation(rotation + 180);
}
```

**Zombie.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Player.h"
class Zombie
{
public:
  Zombie();
  Player player;

  sf::Texture zombieTexture;
  sf::Sprite zombieSprite;

  sf::Vector2f zombiePosition;
  sf::Vector2f playerPosition;
  sf::Vector2f direction;
  sf::Vector2f normalizedDir;

  int xPos;
  int yPos;
  float speed;
  void Move();

};
```

**Zombie.cpp**

```
void Zombie::Move()
{

// Make movement
xPos = zombieSprite.getPosition().x;
yPos = zombieSprite.getPosition().y;

zombiePosition = sf::Vector2f(xPos, yPos);

playerPosition = player.GetPosition();

//Incorrectly outputs player position
//This outputs 0 constantly. But why?
std::cout << "X: " << player.playerPosition.x << " Y: " << 
player.playerPosition.y << std::endl;


direction = playerPosition - zombiePosition;
normalizedDir = direction / sqrt(pow(direction.x, 2) + pow(direction.y, 2));

speed = 2;

//Rotate the Zombie relative to player position
const float PI = 3.14159265;

float dx = zombiePosition.x - playerPosition.x;
float dy = zombiePosition.y - playerPosition.y;

float rotation = (atan2(dy, dx)) * 180 / PI;

zombieSprite.setRotation(rotation + 45);

sf::Vector2f currentSpeed = normalizedDir * speed;

zombieSprite.move(currentSpeed);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Bullet.h"
#include "Zombie.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "Arcade Zombies : 
Multiplayer");
window.setFramerateLimit(60);
window.setMouseCursorVisible(false); // Hide cursor
sf::View fixed = window.getView(); // Create a fixed view

//Background
sf::Texture backgroundTexture;
if (!backgroundTexture.loadFromFile("resources/background.png"))
{
    std::cout << "Load failed" << std::endl;

    system("pause");
}

sf::Sprite backgroundSprite;
backgroundSprite.setTexture(backgroundTexture);
backgroundSprite.setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(backgroundSprite.getTexture()- 
>getSize().x, backgroundSprite.getTexture()->getSize().y));
backgroundSprite.setPosition(window.getSize().x, window.getSize().y);
backgroundSprite.scale(sf::Vector2f(1.1f, 0.7f)); // absolute scale factor

//Cursor
sf::Texture cursorTexture;
if (!cursorTexture.loadFromFile("resources/gun-pointer.png"))
{
    std::cout << "Load failed" << std::endl;

    system("pause");
}
sf::Sprite cursorSprite(cursorTexture);
cursorSprite.setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(cursorSprite.getTexture()->getSize().x * 
0.5, cursorSprite.getTexture()->getSize().y * 0.5));

//Player
Player player;
player.playerSprite.setPosition(window.getSize().x / 2.f, window.getSize().y 
- 50);

//Zombie
Zombie zombie;
zombie.zombieSprite.setPosition(window.getSize().x / 2.f, window.getSize().y 
/ 2.f);
zombie.zombieSprite.scale(sf::Vector2f(0.3f, 0.3f));

//Bullet
Bullet bullet1;
std::vector<Bullet> bullets;
int shootTimer = 0;

//Sound
sf::SoundBuffer gunBuffer, footstepBuffer;
if (!gunBuffer.loadFromFile("resources/gun_shot_sound.wav"))
{
    std::cout << "Load failed" << std::endl;
}

sf::Sound gunSound;
gunSound.setBuffer(gunBuffer);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    //Update
    player.movePlayer(window);

    //Zombie
    zombie.Move();

    //Shoot
    if (shootTimer < 20)
        shootTimer++;

    if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left) && shootTimer >= 20)
    {
        gunSound.play();
        bullet1.bulletSprite.setOrigin(
        sf::Vector2f(bullet1.bulletSprite.getTexture()->getSize().x * 0.5, 
        bullet1.bulletSprite.getTexture()->getSize().y * 0.5));
        bullet1.bulletSprite.setPosition(player.playerPosition);
        bullet1.currentVelocity = player.aimDirNorm * bullet1.maxSpeed;
        bullet1.bulletSprite.setRotation(player.rotation + 90);
        bullets.push_back(Bullet(bullet1));
        shootTimer = 0;

    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
    {
        bullets[i].bulletSprite.move(bullets[i].currentVelocity);

        if (bullets[i].bulletSprite.getPosition().x < 0 || 
            bullets[i].bulletSprite.getPosition().x > window.getSize().x ||
            bullets[i].bulletSprite.getPosition().y < 0 || 
            bullets[i].bulletSprite.getPosition().y > window.getSize().y)
        {
            bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + i);
        }
    }

    // Set mouse position        
    cursorSprite.setPosition(static_cast<sf::Vector2f> 
    (sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)));

    //Draw
    window.clear();
    window.setView(fixed);
    window.draw(backgroundSprite);
    window.draw(player.playerSprite);
    window.draw(zombie.zombieSprite);
    window.draw(cursorSprite);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
    {
        window.draw(bullets[i].bulletSprite);
    }

    window.display();

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Btw you forgot parentheses on your divide by length when normalizing.

Answer (score 1):

You create your `Player` in `main.cpp`, inside `main()`. You also set up the player's initial position here, and every time through your main loop you call `movePlayer` on this player to move it around the world. This is all mostly fine.

Your zombie, however, which you declare in `main()` just after the player... the zombie has it's own *copy* of the player, because you declared `Player player;` in the `Zombie` class. The zombie uses the zombie's player, which is always at zero because it is a *different* player than the one in `main()`.

You probably need your zombie to have a pointer to the player it wants to follow, so you should change your Zombie class to look more like:

```
class Zombie {
  public:
    Zombie();
    Player* player; // Note: now a pointer!
...
```

And then, in `main()`, make sure you give that zombie the address of the player to follow:

```
Zombie zombie;
zombie.player = &player;
...
```

Note that because you've changed the type of the player inside `Zombie` to a pointer, you'll need to change how you access it in `Zombie`: you have to use `player->` instead of `player.` to access methods and fields of the `Player` object.